# Java/Android use one obj pointer to reference 2 class

Tags: java, android, object, reference

Say I need a global obj pointer, like this:

```
/** UI：Fragment頁面提供 */
public static FragmentPagerAdapter PAGER=null;
```

At first, it will pointed to this class

```
public class HomePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{...}
```

But sometime, I would like to point it to another class like following

```
public class MyListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{...}
```

Is that possible ?

Comment: yes, you can use an object of the base class to point to any of its derived classes.

Comment: Perhaps it's obvious but make it clear does not harm: don't forget to cast PAGER whenever you need to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly possible. Parent class reference can hold reference to any child class. I.e both of the following statements are valid:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter PAGER=null;
PAGER=new HomePagerAdapter();
PAGER=new MyListPagerAdapter();
```

Comment: I expect it is possible at first, but my eclipse shows error on it, makes me doubt myself... After few hours fight with this, I restart eclipse(eclipse consume out my memory), and that error just gone......Seems I had ask a stupid question, sorry and thanks guy :-)

Answer (score 1):

**`extends`** is used to inherit a child class from a parent class (also known as a base class).

A parent class can have **multiple children** and thus you can extend many classes from a single parent class.

It means that an object of the ***base class can point to any of the classes derived from it***, if that is what you are trying to do.

```
.
.
    PAGER=new HomePagerAdapter();
    PAGER=new MyListPagerAdapter();
.
.
```

So, ***yes***, it is absolutely possible.

Comment: It's good that you give the rationale. My gut feeling is that the OP would have appreciated a clear conclusion in addition, such as "yes" or "no". ;)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I just ask a stupid question. eclipse's error makes me doubt myself, and after restart it, the error just go away... I was stupid today...T_T"

Comment: It is alright. Happens to the best of us. And dont forget to `clean` your project every once in a while. Helps to remove such errors.